# Are we using transformed or original series to fit a time series model?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, arima, unit-root

I would like to know whether one can use the transformed series to fit a model or not. For example, `fitsereies=auto.arima(differenced_series)` or `fitsereies=auto.arima(original_series)`?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question and would require a long and elaborate answer to consider a variety of situations. A couple of points:

1. It depends on what you want to do with your model; perhaps fitting the model to original data is what you need to measure a particular effect or test a particular hypothesis, but fitting it to transformed data is not that helpful as you can no longer estimate that effect or test that hypothesis.
2. It depends also on whether the model is suitable for original vs. transformed data; it is a bad idea to fit a model to original data if the model assumptions are not satisfied (e.g. you get heteroskedastic residuals where homoskedasticity is assumed), but perhaps the assumptions will be satisfied for transformed data (e.g. you stabilize the residual variance using transformed data), which may motivate that choice.

However, at least your example is simple. Differencing is a relatively simple transformation and it can be allowed for within `auto.arima` by specifying the argument `stationary=FALSE` (which is the default value). KPSS test will be used to test for stationarity and if rejected, the data will be differenced; other tests (augmented Dickey-Fuller, Phillips-Perron) can be used as alternatives, see argument `test`. So if you are satisfied with these tests for determining whether the series should be differenced, you can let `auto.arima` do that. If not, you can difference manually and supply differenced data to `auto.arima`; then you may want to set the argument `stationary=TRUE`, unless you want to allow for (but not force) another round of differencing.